# Compute $0.y_1y_2y_1y_2y_1y_2...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Any tips? I'm taking $$Sn = \frac{y_1}{10} + \frac{y_2}{100} +\frac{y_1}{1000} + $$ and then I find $$\frac{S_n}{100}=...$$

I do $$Sn - \frac{S_n}{100}$$ and go on from there but I can't find the right answer. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**heuristics:** Let $x=0.abababab\dots$, consider $100x$.
$$
100x = x+10a+  b\implies x=  \frac{10a+b}{99}
$$

**formal proof:**
$$
x = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{10a}{100^k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b}{100^k}
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{10a+b}{100^k}=
(10a+b)\frac1{100}\frac 1{1-\frac 1{100}}=\frac{10a+b}{99}
$$

Comment: This is what I found initially but the notes here say $$\frac{y_1y_2}{99}$$

Comment: @user3601507 - $\frac{y_1y_2}{99}$ does not mean $\frac{y_1*y_2}{99}$, it means $\frac{10y_1+y_2}{99}$ as suggested by mookid above. Each $y$ is supposed to represent a digit in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} y_1 y_2 (1/(100))^i$ , and note that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (1/100)^i$ is a geometric series with ratio $\frac{1}{100}$.

In this case, $y_1y_2$ denotes the number with $y_1 $ in the tens place and $y_2$ in the ones place, not $y_1*y_2$.